# How can I loop scraping data for multiple pages in a website using python and beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, loops, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from the PGA.com website to get a table of all of the golf courses in the United States. In my CSV table I want to include the Name of the golf course ,Address ,Ownership ,Website , Phone number. With this data I would like to geocode it and place into a map and have a local copy on my computer

I utilized Python and Beautiful Soup4 to extract my data. I have reached as far to extract the data and import it into a CSV but I am now having a problem of scraping data from multiple pages on the PGA website. I want to extract ALL THE GOLF COURSES but my script is limited only to one page I want to loop it in away that it will capture all data for golf courses from all pages found in the PGA site. There are about 18000 gold courses and 900 pages to capture data

Attached below is my script. I need help on creating code that will capture ALL data from the PGA website and not just one site but multiple. In this manner it will provide me with all the data of gold courses in the United States.

Here is my script below:

```
import csv
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.pga.com/golf-courses/search?searchbox=Course+Name&searchbox_zip=ZIP&distance=50&price_range=0&course_type=both&has_events=0"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data1=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-nothing-1"})
g_data2=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-nothing"})

courses_list=[]

for item in g_data2:
     try:
          name=item.contents[1].find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-title"})[0].text
     except:
          name=''
     try:
          address1=item.contents[1].find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-address"})[0].text
     except:
          address1=''
     try:
          address2=item.contents[1].find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-city-state-zip"})[0].text
     except:
          address2=''
     try:
          website=item.contents[1].find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-website"})[0].text
     except:
          website=''   
     try:
          Phonenumber=item.contents[1].find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-work-phone"})[0].text
     except:
          Phonenumber=''      

     course=[name,address1,address2,website,Phonenumber]
     courses_list.append(course)

     with open ('filename5.csv','wb') as file:
          writer=csv.writer(file)
          for row in courses_list:
               writer.writerow(row)    

#for item in g_data1:
     #try:
          #print item.contents[1].find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-counter"})[0].text
     #except:
          #pass  
     #try:
          #print item.contents[1].find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-course-type"})[0].text
     #except:
          #pass

#for item in g_data2:
   #try:
      #print item.contents[1].find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-title"})[0].text
   #except:
      #pass
   #try:
      #print item.contents[1].find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-address"})[0].text
   #except:
      #pass
   #try:
      #print item.contents[1].find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-city-state-zip"})[0].text
   #except:
      #pass
```

This script only captures 20 at a time and I want to capture all in one script which account for 18000 golf courses and 900 pages to scrape form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The PGA website's search have multiple pages, the url follows the pattern:

```
http://www.pga.com/golf-courses/search?page=1 # Additional info after page parameter here
```

this means you can read the content of the page, then change the value of page by 1, and read the the next page.... and so on.

```
import csv
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for i in range(907):      # Number of pages plus one 
    url = "http://www.pga.com/golf-courses/search?page={}&searchbox=Course+Name&searchbox_zip=ZIP&distance=50&price_range=0&course_type=both&has_events=0".format(i)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

    # Your code for each individual page here
```

Comment: So I have tried using your given script but I still get individual responses for each page giving 20. The given code had given me the last set of data on page 907

Comment: I am trying to create a function but I still only get 20 values and not the entirety of the data. any comments?

Comment: What I think is happening, is your code is writing over the CSV file every time it iterates.

Try opening your file with the append file mode instead: `with open('filename', 'a') as file:` instead

Comment: so I tried it again and it looks like the code is just repeating itself and thoughts on how to go about this?

Comment: It repeats itself, but the url used to fetch the page is changed slightly everytime.

I have used a [`string.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format)  function to change the page number in the url each iteration.

Comment: Weird thing though is that when run it. the first iteration is repeated three times then it takes the last three pages of the pga website and adds to the csv but nothing else. am I missing anything or doing something wrong? I copied your code and placed in mine. your input is highly appreciated!

Comment: You're right, that is weird; I cant think of anything your doing wrong. Try print out the list before you append to the file to debug if the right data is being downloaded. This will help find if it is an error with the downloading of the webpages, or the writing to the csv file.

Answer (score 4):

if you still read this post , you can try this code too....

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file = "Details.csv"
f = open(file, "w")
Headers = "Name,Address,City,Phone,Website\n"
f.write(Headers)
for page in range(1,5):
    url = "http://www.pga.com/golf-courses/search?page={}&searchbox=Course%20Name&searchbox_zip=ZIP&distance=50&price_range=0&course_type=both&has_events=0".format(page)
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    Title = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"views-field-nothing"})
    for i in Title:
        try:
            name = i.find("div", {"class":"views-field-title"}).get_text()
            address = i.find("div", {"class":"views-field-address"}).get_text()
            city = i.find("div", {"class":"views-field-city-state-zip"}).get_text()
            phone = i.find("div", {"class":"views-field-work-phone"}).get_text()
            website = i.find("div", {"class":"views-field-website"}).get_text()
            print(name, address, city, phone, website)
            f.write("{}".format(name).replace(",","|")+ ",{}".format(address)+ ",{}".format(city).replace(",", " ")+ ",{}".format(phone) + ",{}".format(website) + "\n")
        except: AttributeError
f.close()
```

where it is written range(1,5) just change that with 0,to the last page , and you will get all details in CSV, i tried very hard to get your data in proper format but it's hard:).

Comment: hi there  - i run this on ATOM on a mx-linux and i get back the following issue: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martin/.atom/python/examples/bs_golf.py", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
ImportError: No module named request
[Finished in 0.82s]`

whats all this - do i need to have the urlopen installed on my machine!? Love to hear from you

Answer (score 2):

You're putting a link to a single page, it's not going to iterate through each one on its own.

Page 1:

`url = "http://www.pga.com/golf-courses/search?searchbox=Course+Name&searchbox_zip=ZIP&distance=50&price_range=0&course_type=both&has_events=0"`

Page 2:

`http://www.pga.com/golf-courses/search?page=1&searchbox=Course%20Name&searchbox_zip=ZIP&distance=50&price_range=0&course_type=both&has_events=0`

Page 907:
`http://www.pga.com/golf-courses/search?page=906&searchbox=Course%20Name&searchbox_zip=ZIP&distance=50&price_range=0&course_type=both&has_events=0`

Since you're running for page 1 you'll only get 20. You'll need to create a loop that'll run through each page.

You can start off by creating a function that does one page then iterate that function.

Right after the `search?` in the url, starting at page 2, `page=1` begins increasing until page 907 where it's `page=906`.

Comment: Can you help me and provide a function that can loop for rest of the pages? Thanks for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the first solution had a repetition of the first instance, that is because the 0 page and 1 page is the same page. This is resolved by specifying the start page in the range function. Example below...

```
     for i in range(1, 907):     #Number of pages plus one
        url = "http://www.pga.com/golf-courses/search?page={}&searchbox=Course+Name&searchbox_zip=ZIP&distance=50&price_range=0&course_type=both&has_events=0".format(i)
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html5lib")   #Can use whichever parser you prefer

# Your code for each individual page here
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this same exact problem and the solutions above did not work.  I solved mine by accounting for cookies. A requests session helps.  Create a session and it'll pull all the pages you need by inserting a cookie to all the numbered pages.

```
import csv
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.pga.com/golf-courses/search?searchbox=Course+Name&searchbox_zip=ZIP&distance=50&price_range=0&course_type=both&has_events=0"

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

The PGA website has changed this question has been asked.

It seems they organize all courses by: **State > City > Course**

In light of this change and the popularity of this question, here's how I'd solve this problem today.

Step 1 - Import everything we'll need:

```py
import time
import random
from gazpacho import Soup   # https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho
from tqdm import tqdm       # to keep track of progress
```

Step 2 - Scrape all the state URL endpoints:

```py
URL = "https://www.pga.com"

def get_state_urls():
    soup = Soup.get(URL + "/play")
    a_tags = soup.find("ul", {"data-cy": "states"}, mode="first").find("a")
    state_urls = [URL + a.attrs['href'] for a in a_tags]
    return state_urls

state_urls = get_state_urls()
```

Step 3 - Write a function to scrape all the city links:

```py
def get_state_cities(state_url):
    soup = Soup.get(state_url)
    a_tags = soup.find("ul", {"data-cy": "city-list"}).find("a")
    state_cities = [URL + a.attrs['href'] for a in a_tags]
    return state_cities

state_url = state_urls[0]
city_links = get_state_cities(state_url)
```

Step 4 - Write a function to scrape all of the courses:

```py
def get_courses(city_link):
    soup = Soup.get(city_link)
    courses = soup.find("div", {"class": "MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-12 MuiGrid-grid-md-6"}, mode="all")
    return courses

city_link = city_links[0]
courses = get_courses(city_link)
```

Step 5 - Write a function to parse all the useful info about a course:

```py
def parse_course(course):
    return {
        "name": course.find("h5", mode="first").text,
        "address": course.find("div", {'class': "jss332"}, mode="first").strip(),
        "url": course.find("a", mode="first").attrs["href"]
    }

course = courses[0]
parse_course(course)
```

Step 6 - Loop through everything and save:

```py
all_courses = []
for state_url in tqdm(state_urls):
    city_links = get_state_cities(state_url)
    time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 10) / 10)
    for city_link in city_links:
        courses = get_courses(city_link)
        time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 10) / 10)
        for course in courses:
            info = parse_course(course)
            all_courses.append(info)
```